# jasmine: Is this the only difference between returnValue and callFake?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine, mocking

The only difference between callFake and returnValue is that callFake can return different values on the basis of custom logic (parameters/environment)?

Are there any other differences?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

callFake(() => {...}) takes a call back function

> 1. If we just want a return value when a service method is called then we can use any of `and.callFake` or `and.returnValue`

component file:

```
@Component(...)
export class DependencyComponent {
  constructor(private service: RandomService){....}
  .....
  sampleMethod() {
   return this.service.randomMethod();
  }
  .....
}
```

unit test case for above component:

```
it('test callFake vs returnValue', () => {
  let randomService= new RandomService();
  let component = new DependencyComponent(randomService);
  spyOn(randomService, 'randomMethod').and.callFake(() => 4)
  expect(component.sampleMethod()).toBe(4)
  spyOn(randomService, 'randomMethod').and.returnValue(10);
  expect(component.sampleMethod()).toBe(10)
})
```

in above case both the ways are correct.

> 2. Suppose we are passing a parameter to service method to perform its logic then in that case we have to use `and.callFake((param) => {...})`. Here `param` parameter will be the argument passed to the spied method.

component file:

```
@Component(...)
export class DependencyComponent {
  constructor(private service: RandomService){....}
  .....
  sampleMethod(val) {
  return this.service.randomMethod(val);
  }
  .....
}
```

unit test case for above component:

```
it('test callFake vs returnValue', () => {
  let randomService= new RandomService();
  let component = new DependencyComponent(randomService);
  spyOn(randomService, 'randomMethod').and.callFake((param) => param+4)
  expect(component.sampleMethod(4)).toBe(8);
  expect(component.sampleMethod(12)).toBe(16)
})
```

when `component.sampleMethod(4)` is executed it will call `this.service.randomMethod(4)`. As `randomMethod()` is being spied using `and.callFake` therefore `4` will be passed as argument of call back function of `and.callFake`.

Answer (score 1):

Clear difference or benefit can be seen when callfake has callback function as parameter .

Answer (score 1):

I have observed a strange behavior and differece between `returnValue` and `callFake` in my Angular 8 code (with jasmine). Below is my code,

```
spyOn(object, 'method').and.returnValue(Promise.reject('error'));
```

When I have the above code, when I call `tick()` the above spy method gets invoked on its own - without calling the component method. That results in my test failing with error `Uncaught promise error`. However, when I change the above code to this,

```
spyOn(object, 'method').and.callFake(() => Promise.reject('error'));
```

the code work as expected and the spy method is called only when invoked from within the component.

Unable to understand what is the difference here and why `callFake` works.

Comment: For future seekers who stumble upon the same issue, you might want to read [this Github discussion](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/issues/1590#issuecomment-462403387) about using `callFake()` vs `returnValue` when dealing with promise rejection.

TL;DR: When working with promise rejection, always use `callFake()`

Answer (score 0):

Both are same.. returnValue is just syntactical sugar over callfake is what I understand.